# How does this snippet in Chapter 7 of Eloquent Javascript work?

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in the chapter 7 of Eloquent Javascript. At the beginning of the project, we are supposed to convert a list of roads (recorded in an array of strings) into a data structure. The author directly gives the solution, but I have no idea how the function work. Can anyone help give an explanation on it? Many Thanks!

The list of roads and its corresponding array:

[the pic of the roads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nb5RA.png)

```
const roads = [
    "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
    "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
    "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
    "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
    "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
    "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
    "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
];
```

> The array of strings isn’t very easy to work with. What we’re
>   interested in is the destinations that we can reach from a given
>   place. Let’s convert the list of roads to a data structure that, for
>   each place, tells us what can be reached from there.

This is the function that converts the list into a data structure:

```js
function buildGraph(edges) {

    let graph = Object.create(null);


// How does this addEdge function work at all?
    function addEdge(from, to) {

        if (graph[from] == null) {
            graph[from] = [to];  //Why assign graph[from] to [to] instead of to?
        } else {
            graph[from].push(to);
        }
    }

    for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
        addEdge(from, to);
        addEdge(to, from);
    }

    return graph;

}

const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);
```

Comment: Possibly cleaner: `if (graph[from] == null) { graph[from] = []; } graph[from].push(to);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before diving into the code, I suggest you to take a carefully look at the input array and at the JavaScript object generated as output.

The input array is just an array of strings. Let's make it simple:

```js
roads = [
  "A-B",
  "A-C",
  "A-P",
  "B-T",
  "D-E",
  "D-T",
  "..."
  ]
```

The expected output (JavaScript object) looks like this:

```js
roadGraph = 
{ 'A': [ 'B', 'C', 'P' ],
  'B': [ 'A', 'T' ],
  'C': [ 'A' ],
  'P': [ 'A', 'M' ],
  ...
}
```

So, the **addEdge** function must be able to:

### 1. Create a new property (inside the JS object) if it doesn't already exist;

```js
if (graph[from] == null) {
      graph[from] = [to];
    }
```

At the first iteration of the for loop, if we replace with the first element of the array **roads**, we have:

```js
if (graph['A'] == null) {  // In fact, the property 'A' still doesn't exist.
      graph['A'] = ['B'];  // So let's create it and assign an array
    }                      // containing the string 'B' as its value.
```

Still at the first iteration, the function **addEdge** is called again. So we have:

```
if (graph['B'] == null) {  // Also, the property 'B' still doesn't exist.
      graph['B'] = ['A'];  // So let's create it and assign an array
    }                      // containing the string 'A' as its value.
```

### 2. Push a new value into the array of values of each property that already exists.

```js
else {
        graph[from].push(to);
    }
```

So, at second iteration of the for loop, if we replace with the second element of the array **roads**, the property 'A' will already exist, so:

```js
else {
        graph['A'].push('C');
    }
```

Thus, at the end of all iterations, we will have the **roadGraph** object that each property stores an array of connected destinations.

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildGraph(edges) {
let graph = Object.create(null);
    // So we're creating an OBJECT whose 'keys' are the names of the starting 
    positions(from) and it's values are the possible destinations(to) for each starting position. 
    // Each 'from' consists of an ARRAY of destinations which are other places in the village.
    function addEdge(from, to){
        if (graph[from] == null){
            // If this starting position doesn't exist, create an element with the name
            // of the starting address as the 'key' and it's 'value' will be
            // an array with the destination inside it. 
            // This is our starting position.
            graph[from] = [to]; 

            // Example Output: {"Alice's House": [Bob's House]}
        } 
        else {
            // Else, if the starting address(from) property already
            // exists, add a destination to the array of destinations.
            graph[from].push(to);
        }
    }
    for (let [from, to] of edges.map(r => r.split("-"))) {
        // The 'split' method returns an ARRAY of strings. So that's why it iterates
        // over edges looking for an array with two elements in them.
        // Ex: The string "Alice's House-Bob's House" in const roads becomes
        // [Alice's House, Bob's House]

        // edges.map will return an ARRAY of ARRAYS of [from, to]. The output will look like this:
        // [[Alice's House, Bob's House], [Alice's House, Cabin], [Alice's House, Post Office], etc...]

        // It then uses the addEdge function to create a new property(we can also call this a 'key') 
        // on the edges OBJECT.

        addEdge(from, to);
        addEdge(to, from);
    }
        return graph;
    }
```

Here's something that also might be confusing you:

Why does addEdge get called twice at the end?

In the context of the 'for' loop, 'from' and 'to' represent the first and second element in the edge array respectively. So [from, to] means [first, second].

```
addEdge(first, second)
addEdge(second, first)
```

Or using the [Alice's House, Bob's House] example.

```
addEdge("Alice's House", "Bob's House")
addEdge("Bob's House", "Alice's House")
```

I hope I helped clear some of your questions up.